# Can't execute a .sh script from mounted disk (Ubuntu 18.04): zsh: permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh, fstab

Ubuntu 18.04 - Installed Zsh and Oh-My-Zsh from [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Given the following

```
echo '#!/bin/bash\n\nls ~;' >> myscript.sh
chmod 755 ./myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
```

Executed in my home folder, all goes as expected and it lists files in my home folder

> output omitted for brevity -- it worked and listed files as the script intended

Executed in a secondary drive I get the output listed below (my fstab config is listed lower in this question).

```
╭─user@host /media/user/raw/scripts
╰─$ echo '#!/bin/bash\n\nls ~;' >> myscript.sh
╭─user@host /media/user/raw/scripts  
╰─$ chmod 755 ./myscript.sh
╭─user@host /media/user/raw/scripts  
╰─$ ./myscript.sh 
zsh: permission denied: ./myscript.sh
```

My /etc/fstab

```
╭─user@host /media/user/raw/scripts  
╰─$ cat /etc/fstab                                                                130 ↵
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=<<some_uuid>> /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=<<some_uuid>>  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/<<some_uuid>> /media/user/raw auto user,rw,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Since this executes fine in my home folder and not on this mounted drive, I'm thinking the issue is somewhere within the fstab configuration.  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried the same in bash and the result was the same (bash: ./myscript.sh: Permission denied).  It appears to be an issue with how I've mounted that particular disk, not with the interpreter

Comment: [Can't execute a script on a mounted external drive](https://superuser.com/q/99635/173513), [How do I execute a file from a FAT USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/23128), etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are implicitly specifying `noexec`, which means that no files on the device will be executable.

Here's `man mount`:

> **user**
>
> Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the mounting user is written to the mtab file (or to the private libmount file in /run/mount on systems  without  a  regular  mtab) so that this same user can unmount the filesystem again.  **This option implies the options noexec**, nosuid, and nodev (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line user,exec,dev,suid).

The same paragraph also suggests the fix: use the `user,exec` to re-enable execution in a user mountable fs.

Comment: You're right.  That was the problem.  I read the man page too, but stopped at "Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem", not realizing user was a macro option.  Thanks for your help @that other guy!

Comment: Can you provide any more detail? I can't execute in a mounted drive, but I don't understand how to go about changing the user,exec flags...

Comment: OP had declared the mount and options in `/etc/fstab` so that's where they'd change it